# Built in About Application Dialog in OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there way I can quickly set up an About Window for my OS X app without creating a window and adding elements to it from scratch? Something like HIAboutBox but which works on OS X 10.8 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa has built-in support for displaying a standard about box, and projects created from any of Xcode's templates will have this wired up to the "About MyApplication" menu item in the application menu. It works by calling `-[NSApplication orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:]`. It automatically pulls the basic information from your application bundle (icon, name, version, build number, copyright notice). It also supports displaying extra information by looking for a file named Credits.html / Credits.rtf / Credits.rtfd in the application bundle.